# rails 3 remote form ajax for part of the form

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a search form in my rails 3 app. This form has some dropdown menus which are used to set different search criteria. The form then makes a search for a model called "item", based on what was selected. This results in a list of items being created and paginated. This is the original form tag I used:

```
<%= form_tag("", :method => "post") do %>
```

I then wanted to attach a "ajax" listener to one of the dropdown menus (to affect another dropdown), i still want to submit the rest of the form using POST without ajax (for the "normal" search). The ajax part is only for displaying different search criteria. I tried this form tag:

```
<%= form_for(:itemsbylocation, :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

Unfortunately that breaks something in the form... I can't submit it anymore using POST. It triggers a simple javascript though (from the js template), which only makes an alert.

So.. The form started as a simple form using POST, no ajax, and that worked fine. I then wanted ajax for a small part of the form, just a dropdown or two, so I tried another type of form using "remote". I still want to the main search (for items) to use POST (no Ajax)....
Does anyone have any tips in this case? 
Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I decided to bypass the rails ajax "remote" way for forms for my dropdowns, i.e I DO NOT use "remote", I don't even use forms. Maybe there's some drawback when doing that.. like security issues?, but it works for me. I just added this javascript (listener) code (see below) to the general javascript. I added a new controller action (categories/category_changed), a route and a js-template. In the javascript view I can then manipulate the dropdowns as needed.
...

```
    $("#type").change(function(){
    var catValue = $(this).val();       
    var formaction = "/categories/category_changed/"+catValue;

    args = "id="+catValue;
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: formaction,
    data: args,
    dataType: "script"
    }) 
});
```

...

**End of Edit**

Some code...

The partial:

```
   <%= form_for(:itemsbylocation, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <label class="left search" for="search-inp">
                <%= f.text_field :searchstr %>
            </label>
      <select class="custom" id="type" name="cat">
          <option value=''>Choose category</option>
      <% @super_categories.each do |supercat| %>
              <option class="optgroup"><%= supercat.name %></option> 
          <% supercat.category.each do |cat| %>
                 <option <%= highlight_if_selected params[:cat], cat.id %> value='<%= cat.id %>'><%= cat.name %></option>
              <% end %>
       <% end %>            
    </select>

    <select name="loc" class="custom">
      <option value=''>Choose location</option>         
            <% @locations.each do |location| %>
                            <option <%= highlight_if_selected @selected_location, location.id %>
                            value='<%= location.id
                            %>'><%= location.name %></option>              
                           <% end %>
    </select>
            <div class="clr h-small"></div>
            <div id="buttonset">
                <input type="checkbox"
                <% if get_mode(params,
                @modes['sell']) %>
                checked="checked" <% end %>
                value="<%= @modes['sell'] %>" name="mode_id_<%= @modes['sell'] %>" id="search-1" class="checkbox" />
                <label class="checkbox" for="search-1">Selling</label>
                <input type="checkbox" <% if get_mode(params,
                @modes['buy']) %>
                checked="checked" <% end %>
                value="<%= @modes['buy'] %>" name="mode_id_<%= @modes['buy'] %>" id="search-2" class="checkbox" />
                <label class="checkbox" for="search-2">Buying</label>
                <input type="checkbox" <% if get_mode(params,
                @modes['to_rent']) %>
                checked="checked" <% end %>
                value="<%= @modes['to_rent'] %>" name="mode_id_<%= @modes['to_rent'] %>" id="search-3" class="checkbox" />
                                    <label class="checkbox"
                                    for="search-3">Renting</label>

                <input type="checkbox" <% if get_mode(params,
                @modes['wish_to_rent']) %>
                checked="checked" <% end %>
                value="<%= @modes['wish_to_rent'] %>" name="mode_id_<%= @modes['wish_to_rent'] %>" id="search-4" class="checkbox" />
                                    <label class="checkbox"
                                    for="search-4">Wish to rent</label>
            </div>              

            <!-- input type="submit" class="btn
            search-btn" value="Search" / -->
            <%= f.submit %>



    </div>

   <% end %> <!-- form -->
```

The controller (The js template only contains an alert):

```
# GET /items/1
# GET /items/1.json
def list
  @selected_location = (params[:loc]) ? params[:loc] : params[:id]
  @items = Item.search_items(@selected_location, params[:page])
  @modes = Mode.modes_for_search
  @super_categories = Supercategory.find(:all)
  @locations = Location.locations    
  @subcategories = Subcategory.where(:category_id => params[:cat]).order("name")

  @has_price_info = true # look up based on category id
  @show_images=true # look up in params or in user session

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # list.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @items }
    format.js
  end
end
```

Comment: wow, you have a ton of stuff in there. could you boil your code down to the important stuff and format it a little nicer? Have you tried watching [railscast 88](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus?view=comments) about dynamic dropdown menu forms?

Comment: By the way.. Is it possible to do nested forms in rails?

Comment: I found a solution to my problem, see "Edit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, see the "Edit" section.